# Where can i find valid webapp endpoint in Whatsapp Business API integration

Tags: api, docker, whatsapp

I am new in whatsapp business API integration and i successfully installed Docker and postman collection.

Referring below link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance

Now in postman collection they mentioned regarding `{{ URL }}`

Collection Link : `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/postman`

***`The first thing you should replace is the URL which represents the webapp endpoint. You'll see that all of the requests will reference this variable via {{URL}} so it's important you get this right.`***

How can i get this Valid URL ?

I tried hard but unable to find it.

Help me if anybody know this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed whatsApp business API over docker setup .. then your endpoint url will be https://localhost:9090 .. replace "localhost" with ip of server if required.

Simply, use command netstat -nltp|grep 9090, and check on which ip the port is open for.